# UWP C#: Save and load Virtualkey from configuration file

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm toying around with an Universal Windows App for the first time and want to save and load Virtualkeys from a configuration text file on certain events. I've set up the writing part but I'm kinda stuck on how to translate the "key string" from the text file to a Virtualkey.

Some shortened code for better understanding:

```
    private IDictionary<GamepadButtons, VirtualKey> assignedButtons = new Dictionary<GamepadButtons, VirtualKey>();

    // Read keys from dic
    private void GetKeys()
    {
        if (assignedButtons.ContainsKey(GamepadButtons.Aux1)) { aux1_str = (assignedButtons[GamepadButtons.Aux1]).ToString(); } else if (!assignedButtons.ContainsKey(GamepadButtons.Aux1)) { aux1_str = "0"; }
    }

    // Write config file
    async private void WriteConfig()
    {
        appfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
            config = await appfolder.CreateFileAsync("config.ini", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var writer = await config.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            string[] paddles = { aux1_str };
            using (StreamWriter ConfigWriter = new StreamWriter(writer)) { foreach (string line in paddles) ConfigWriter.WriteLine(line); }
        }
        catch { };
    }

    // Read config text file
    async private void GetConfig()
    {
        appfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
            config = await appfolder.GetFileAsync("config.ini");
            var reader = await config.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            StreamReader ConfigReader = new StreamReader(reader);
            aux1_str = ConfigReader.ReadLine();
        }
        catch { };
    }

    // Assign keys 
    private void PushKeys()
    {
        assignedButtons[GamepadButtons.Aux1] = ???
    }
```

Now, I would probably know my way around if I had access to System.Windows.Forms or if I could use MapVirtualKey but neither is an option for UWP.

Any ideas how to solve this issue? Maybe there is a better way to store the Virtualkey to a text file (numeric)? Again, I'm kinda stuck due to the app being UWP.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: The `GamepadButtons` is a enum type, it seems there is no Aux1 in it.